# Get data from MySQL after draggable swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm having problem to get data from mysql when two `draggable` elements are swapped. Because swap action is performed inside `$.post` function.

```
$(function () {
    var parent_div_data;
    var field_array = ["tire_number", "bar", "mm_1", "mm_2", "mm_3"];
    $(".tire").draggable({
        containment: ".table_edit_data",
        scroll: false,
        appendTo: "body",
        cursor: "move",
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: "invalid",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            parent_div_data = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if ($('#' + parent_div_data).children().length == 0) {
                    $.each(field_array, function (index, value) {
                        $('#' + parent_div_data).parent().find('.' + value).val('');
                    });
                }
            }, 50);

        }
    });

    $("#tire_div").droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        accept: ".tire",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#tire_div").append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    });

    $(".droppable_1, .droppable_2, .droppable_3, .droppable_4, .droppable_5, .droppable_6").droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        accept: ".tire",
        activeClass: "div-droppable-default",
        hoverClass: "div-droppable-hover",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var url = 'class=<?= $this->reg['
            class '] ?>&"&action=get_tire_data';
            var this_data = $(this);

            $.post('index.php?' + url, {
                tire_id: $(ui.draggable).attr('data')
            }, function (data) { //data attribute contains `id`. And data is returned.                  
                if (this_data.find(".tire").length == 1) {
                    var first = this_data.find(':first-child'); //where elements swap is performed
                    $('#' + parent_div_data).append(first);
                    // $.each(field_array, function(index, value) {                         
                    // $('#' + parent_div_data).parent().find('.' + value).val(first.attr(value));
                    // });
                }
                this_data.append($(ui.draggable));
                this_data.parent().find('.tire_number').val(data.tire_number);
                this_data.parent().find('.bar').val(data.bar);
                this_data.parent().find('.mm_1').val(data.mm_1);
                this_data.parent().find('.mm_2').val(data.mm_2);
                this_data.parent().find('.mm_3').val(data.mm_3);
            }, "json");
        }
    });
});
```

Where swap action is performed (see comment in the code), do I need to add another post, to get values again, or can you advice another method. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you want to do after a swap? Can you be more specific.

Comment: @HarryBomrah Each droppable `div` has input fields, which are filled when I drop element. (There are 6 `div` elements total, and each `div` can hold only one draggable element, if you drag another they are swapped). My problem if elements are swapped only one `div` input fields are filled. Because element swap action is inside `$.post` and this element cant get data from `mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you can add call a function which makes one more request to server  whenever there is a swap

```
$.post('index.php?' + url, {
            tire_id: $(ui.draggable).attr('data')
        }, function (data) { //data attribute contains `id`. And data is returned.                  
            if (this_data.find(".tire").length == 1) {
                var first = this_data.find(':first-child'); //where elements swap is performed
                $('#' + parent_div_data).append(first);
                //call your function here 
               // for ex getData(first);
            }
            this_data.append($(ui.draggable));
            this_data.parent().find('.tire_number').val(data.tire_number);
            this_data.parent().find('.bar').val(data.bar);
            this_data.parent().find('.mm_1').val(data.mm_1);
            this_data.parent().find('.mm_2').val(data.mm_2);
            this_data.parent().find('.mm_3').val(data.mm_3);
        }, "json");
```